# Can't make categories in my webpy blog, bad default value use, using browser direction bar input like alias

Tags: python, blogs, categories, web.py

I'm trying to make categories in my self-developed blog with webpy
I try to make :

> mywebpage.com/c/categorieName

be the input that shows the categorie (like an alias ?¿?)

```
 urls = (   
    '/c/(.*)','index'
)
```

Then the index class is:

```
class index(object):
    def GET(self,cat):
        seleccion = functions.categoria(db,cat)
        #seleccion = db.select('contenido',what="*",order="modificado DESC")
        #print seleccion
        return render.index(seleccion.getThread(),cat)
```

I have a .py document with some helping functions:

```
class categoria(object):
    def __init__(self,datab,nombre='frutas'):
        '''
        Selecciona y asigna una lista o diccionario
        con el contenido de la base de datos dispuesto en
        objetos de la clase noticias.
        '''
        self.datab = datab #objeto database
        self.nombre = nombre #cadena con el nombre de la categoria
        self.n = self.getCat() #calculo del numero de la categoria PROBLEMAS
        self.thread = self.getThread()       


    def getCat(self):
        ''' returns the categorie number stored in the database
        '''
        a = self.datab.select('categorias',where='catName = $nombre', vars=dict(nombre=self.nombre))
        return a[0].catId

    def getThread(self):
        myvars = dict(numero= '%'+str(self.n)+'%' )
        d = self.datab.query("SELECT * FROM contenido WHERE category LIKE $numero", vars= myvars)
        #what="contentTitle,content,'update'",
        return d

    # db.query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x = $x", vars=dict(x='f'), _test=False)

    def __str__(self):
        'some more code, doesn't matter'
```

I have the mysql database correctly configured and contains sample content.
I try to run it usin the feature but the best result i take is to place a default value for variable **cat** that doesn't let me change the category in view with the browsers direction feature.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is with result of `seleccion.getThread` call.

In webpy `db.query` returns `web.iterbetter` that you can iterate only once. You may try to return `d.list()` instead of `d`, it will convert `web.iterbetter` to `list`.

UPD: Perhaps I didn't understand your question, so this is another try:

`'/c/(.*)','index'` mapping means category can be empty, so you either set the default value in your GET function like this: `def GET(self,cat=None):` or change the mapping to `'/c/(.+)','index'` so it will not work with `'/c/'` request path.

Comment: I solved itterbetter problems before this, getThread has well behaviour with the template calls to show the data. If i use '/','index' and call in the browser ,,,.com?cat=nameOfmyCategorie i have no problems changing between categories, now what happens is that if there is a default value, it takes that and doesn't changes if i call another ,,,.com/c/nameofCategorie

Comment: Hey you are awesome! what a good trick that .+ selector then i can make /c/ page to show a list of categories!!, the list() method also helps i can then make some index iteration that i couldnt. Ill post 1 more question by now it doesn't crash my web but the idle says to me that there is an internal server error